# What is the meaning of "rush of battle"?

Tags: word-play

There is a quote that says:

> The rush of battle is a potent and often lethal addiction, for war is a drug, one I ingested for many years.
>
> - Chris Hedges

Does "rush of battle" means to go into a battle, attack, or having the desire to fight?

Answer (score 3):

It is referring to the adrenaline rush of battle, that it is exciting at the same time it is terrifying.

Comment: And what about "for war is a drug"? What does it mean?

Comment: Some servicemen grow to enjoy the excitement of combat, even though it is terrifying; it becomes like an addiction.

Comment: @HozanAli adrenaline is literally a drug.  People are sometimes capable of near super-human feats when under the influence of it.  Hedges isn't saying war is analogous to drugs. He is saying war is quite literally a drug you can become addicted to like any other.

Comment: @eps, I got it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm being pedantic, (or just married to a pharmacist) but the generic prepared drug is called 'adrenaline' with an 'e' at the end, in Europe, and 'epinephrine' in the US. Both not capitalised. Furthermore, Adrenalin (capital A', no 'e' at the end) is a brand name used by Parke, Davis & Co for their proprietary version of this drug.